# Sending an email with bash/ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, email, ubuntu, smtp

So I was trying to write a fairly simple script, and part of it is sending an email. The thing is that script runs without any errors, everything works, but I never get that email. And I believe some gmail pop-up should come if it was successful, I don't get that as well. Walked through this tutorial: `https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/` but issue still persists. Any ideas, what could be done here?

I tried just testing and sending an email from terminal window - same thing

The only warning related to `main.cf` file was
`"warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 42: overriding earlier entry: relayhost ="`
And there a huge bunch of those even though script was run only twice today. 
line 42 in main.cf file is `"relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587"`

Line for it in the script that I use is

```
`mail -s "Subject" -A "info.$NOW.log" my@email.com`
```

Logs:
`Sep 12 09:59:55 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/qmgr[5372]: 3D892636CF: from=<shroomz@shroomz-VirtualBox>, size=370, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 12 09:59:55 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/trivial-rewrite[5481]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 42: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=
Sep 12 09:59:55 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/smtp[5482]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 42: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=
Sep 12 09:59:55 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/tlsmgr[5483]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 42: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=
Sep 12 10:00:03 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/sendmail[5486]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 42: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=
Sep 12 10:00:03 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/postdrop[5487]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 42: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=
Sep 12 10:00:03 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/cleanup[5488]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 42: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=
Sep 12 10:00:03 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/pickup[5371]: 865D06267A: uid=1000 from=<shroomz@shroomz-VirtualBox>
Sep 12 10:00:03 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/cleanup[5488]: 865D06267A: message-id=<20160912070003.865D06267A@shroomz-VirtualBox.lt.emea.csc.com>
Sep 12 10:00:03 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/qmgr[5372]: 865D06267A: from=<shroomz@shroomz-VirtualBox>, size=399, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 12 10:00:03 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/local[5489]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 42: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=
Sep 12 10:00:03 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/bounce[5490]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 42: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=
Sep 12 10:00:03 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/local[5489]: 865D06267A: to=<sarunas.petkevicius@gmail.com>, relay=local, delay=0.04, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "sarunas.petkevicius")
Sep 12 10:00:03 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/cleanup[5488]: 8DBE26267C: message-id=<20160912070003.8DBE26267C@shroomz-VirtualBox.lt.emea.csc.com>
Sep 12 10:00:03 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/bounce[5491]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 42: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=
Sep 12 10:00:03 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/qmgr[5372]: 8DBE26267C: from=<>, size=2406, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 12 10:00:03 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/bounce[5490]: 865D06267A: sender non-delivery notification: 8DBE26267C
Sep 12 10:00:03 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/qmgr[5372]: 865D06267A: removed
Sep 12 10:00:03 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/local[5489]: 8DBE26267C: to=<shroomz@shroomz-VirtualBox>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Sep 12 10:00:03 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/qmgr[5372]: 8DBE26267C: removed
Sep 12 10:00:25 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/smtp[5482]: connect to smtp.gmail.com[74.125.206.108]:587: Connection timed out
Sep 12 10:00:25 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/smtp[5482]: connect to smtp.gmail.com[2a00:1450:400c:c04::6c]:587: Network is unreachable
Sep 12 10:00:55 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/smtp[5482]: connect to smtp.gmail.com[74.125.206.109]:587: Connection timed out
Sep 12 10:00:55 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/bounce[5494]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 42: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=
Sep 12 10:00:55 shroomz-VirtualBox postfix/smtp[5482]: 3D892636CF: to=<user@domain.com>, relay=none, delay=229326, delays=229266/0.06/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to smtp.gmail.com[74.125.206.109]:587: Connection timed out)`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the following: Contents of `main.cf` errors related in `/var/log/mail.log` and your sending command from script.

Comment: I hope I made everything more clear now :)

Comment: you got configuration problem, Please post contents of main.cf , add -v to master.cf like following `smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -v` and  restart postfix service, then send another email and post the contents of `/var/log/mail.log`

Comment: Can't add main.cf normally as ## just mess everything up, It's already hard to read the post as it is

Comment: `telnet 74.125.206.108 587` Use this in terminal, Can you connect ?

Comment: And You have 2x `relayhost=` entry in your main.cf , remove one, there should be only one like this: `relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587`

Comment: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

Comment: There is a network problem then

Comment: Do you have internet access on that host? `ping google.com`, then `ip -a` and paste output here.

Comment: same thing happens on two different networks, home and work. I can ping google, packets go in and out without any problems. ip - a doesn't give me anything, for some reason, just the instructions, how to use it

Comment: You should be able to `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` on the terminal before we can move forward to postfix, did you check your firewall?

Comment: Googling how to do that now :D

Comment: I disabled firewall completely, but still getting connection time out there

Comment: try telnet `mail.gmx.com 587` to see if you only have problem with google. It should respond with `220 gmx.com (mrgmx101) Nemesis ESMTP Service ready`

Comment: Times out as well

Comment: Local or ISP Problem for sure. 587 TCP is blocked somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your network configuration, You need to check the following:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

This probably yield `Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`

Check your internet connection, Firewall rules that maybe blocking outgoing `587` on `TCP`, and your routing table using `ip route list`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "your text " | mail -s subject your@mail.com
```

and you must have configured email sending from host, whatever you have exim or postfix.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but have you actually read the question I asked? :) I know the code line, but it just doesn't work, thats what I am trying to figure out here

Comment: if you cannot telnet to your smtp, so there is 2 possible problems: 1. Your internet provider could block smtp port and the must to do it by default in security reason . Ask you ISP to check settings.   If you has been sending a lots of mail smtp server could block you.   Usually google smtp servers can block users at least 24 hours .